# Desktop Folder Missing Quick Access Context Options (Windows 11)

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, context-menu

I've recently reinstalled Windows 11 (23466.1001), as I got a new SSD. I copied over my old drive's files in a common manner to the new drive, but ran into some issues with my new Desktop folder.

In File Explorer, when navigating to `C:\Users\david\`, when I right click on `Desktop`, I get the normal context options:

[image: Normal Context Options for Desktop]

However, I want my `Desktop` folder pinned to Quick Access, and when I add it there, said context options that would (and have, in the past) appeared there, stop doing so:

[image: Context options missing in Quick Access]

Note: *For what it's worth, the "Open in Visual Studio" option that appears there does not appear to do anything.* The options missing from this menu are still present for Documents, Downloads, etc:

[image: Context menu options exist for other folders]

---

**I have attempted the following to try to fix this, to no avail:**

- Un-pinning and re-pinning Desktop (surprise surprise)
- File Explorer ➜ `•••` ➜ Options ➜ View ➜ `Reset Folders`
- Moved Desktop away from `C:\Users\david\Desktop`, deleted existing folder, moved back to current location (attempt to reset any finicky folder permissions)
- [Steps listed here](https://www.makeuseof.com/reset-folder-view-settings-default-windows-11/) to reset Folder View Settings

  - Removed `Bags` and `BagMRU` from `...\Windows\Shell\` in the registry
  - Batch file to reset explorer to defaults (view settings, nav settings, etc.)
- Reinstalled OneDrive to see if this issue persisted with the OneDrive Desktop folder - it did, the same issue presented itself.

---

I would prefer to not reinstall Windows 11 again, if at all possible.

Comment: I do not know and I could care less why a perfectly good answer was downvoted. It correctly depicted how Windows 11 Quick Access works.

Comment: @john Quick access still exists in Windows 11, on the sidebar. Click any option that you saw there, near the top left of your Explorer Window. Desktop, Downloads, etc. _All_ of them have an option to "unpin from Quick Access". Your post indicated that "quick access does not exist in the sidebar in Windows 11," which is categorically false.

Comment: On top of that, it did not at all attempt to answer the question of why these context options were missing, which was the question. I am not looking for workarounds, or other ways to use Explorer, I am trying to restore missing functionality.

Comment: Not on my Windows 11 Pro machine

Comment: How did you copy the files "in a common manner"? Was `C:\users\yourself` included?

Comment: @harrymc I copied the files inside the folders (i.e. copied all folder from `D:\Users\david\Desktop` to `C:\Users\david\Desktop`), but I did not copy the entire user directory, no.

Comment: If the new `david` account did not get the same System ID (SID) as the old one, you mixed up the ownership and permissions of these files. This might explain it.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, I might have misphrased. I did not copy the Desktop folder itself, just the files within it. I would understand if files inside the Desktop were messed up due to this copying, but the Desktop folder itself has not been touched besides unlinking from OneDrive.

Comment: I think that your problems are related to the method of copy. You don't specify all the folders/contents that you copied, and how, so answering becomes impossible.

Comment: The answer I gave is how Windows 11 works, so answering is not impossible at all.

Comment: Explorer is changing in Windows 11 Insider so what I gave you in my (deleted) answer is correct now and into the future